# Case insensitive 'in'

Tags: python, string, list, case-insensitive

I love using the expression

```
if 'MICHAEL89' in USERNAMES:
    ...
```

where `USERNAMES` is a list.

---

Is there any way to match items with case insensitivity or do I need to use a custom method? Just wondering if there is a need to write extra code for this.

Answer (score 256):

```
username = 'MICHAEL89'
if username.upper() in (name.upper() for name in USERNAMES):
    ...
```

Alternatively:

```
if username.upper() in map(str.upper, USERNAMES):
    ...
```

Or, yes, you can make a custom method.

Comment: `if 'CaseFudge'.lower() in [x.lower() for x in list]`

Comment: `[...]` creates the whole list. `(name.upper() for name in USERNAMES)` would create only a generator and one needed string at a time - massive memory savings if you're doing this operation a lot. (even more savings, if you simply create a list of lowercase usernames that you reuse for checking every time)

Comment: Prefer to lower all keys when building the dict, for performance reasons.

Comment: if [x.lower() for x in list] is a list comprehension, is (name.upper() for name in USERNAMES) a tuple comprehension? Or does it have another name?

Comment: @otocan It's a generator expression.

Comment: @nmichaels thanks, just wanted to know what to google

Answer (score 53):

`str.casefold` is recommended for case-insensitive string matching. [@nmichaels's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627815/9209546) can trivially be adapted.

Use either:

```
if 'MICHAEL89'.casefold() in (name.casefold() for name in USERNAMES):
```

Or:

```
if 'MICHAEL89'.casefold() in map(str.casefold, USERNAMES):
```

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold):

> Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it
>   is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string. For example,
>   the German lowercase letter 'ß' is equivalent to "ss". Since it is
>   already lowercase, `lower()` would do nothing to 'ß'; `casefold()`
>   converts it to "ss".

Answer (score 21):

I would make a *wrapper* so you can be non-invasive.  Minimally, for example...:

```
class CaseInsensitively(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.__s = s.lower()
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__s)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        # ensure proper comparison between instances of this class
        try:
           other = other.__s
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
          try:
             other = other.lower()
          except:
             pass
        return self.__s == other
```

Now, `if CaseInsensitively('MICHAEL89') in whatever:` should behave as required (whether the right-hand side is a list, dict, or set).  (It may require more effort to achieve similar results for string inclusion, avoid warnings in some cases involving `unicode`, etc).

Comment: that doesn't work for dict try if CaseInsensitively('MICHAEL89') in {'Michael89':True}:print "found"

Comment: Xavier: You would need `CaseInsensitively('MICHAEL89') in {CaseInsensitively('Michael89'):True}` for that to work, which probably doesn't fall under "behave as required".

Comment: So much for there being only 1 obvious way to do it. This feels heavy unless it's going to be used a lot. That said, it's very smooth.

Comment: @Nathon, it seems to me that having to invasively alter the container is the "feels heavy" operation.  A completely non-invasive wrapper: how much "lighter" than this could one get?!  Not much;-).  @Xavier, RHS's that are dicts or sets with mixed-case keys/items need their own non-invasive wrappers (part of the short `etc.` and "require more effort" parts of my answer;-).

Comment: My definition of heavy involves writing quite a bit of code to make something that will only be used once, where a less robust but much shorter version would do. If this is going to be used more than once, it's perfectly sensible.

Answer (score 16):

Usually (in oop at least) you shape your object to behave the way you want. `name in USERNAMES` is not case insensitive, so `USERNAMES` needs to change:

```
class NameList(object):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.names = names

    def __contains__(self, name): # implements `in`
        return name.lower() in (n.lower() for n in self.names)

    def add(self, name):
        self.names.append(name)

# now this works
usernames = NameList(USERNAMES)
print someone in usernames
```

The great thing about this is that it opens the path for many improvements, without having to change any code outside the class. For example, you could change the `self.names` to a set for faster lookups, or compute the `(n.lower() for n in self.names)` only once and store it on the class and so on ...

Comment: Unfortunately this loses all the standard list features, like sort, insert, pop, etc.  You could subclass `list` but that doesn't help doing compares in other places.  What if you need a dict instead of a list?  Better to create a case-insensitive string class than a specialized container.

Answer (score 10):

Here's one way:

```
if string1.lower() in string2.lower(): 
    ...
```

For this to work, both `string1` and `string2` objects must be of type `string`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @Jeff that's because one of your elements is a list, and both objects should be a string. Which object is a list?

Comment: I would up vote you, but I cannot unless you edit your answer. You are absolutely right.

Comment: @Jeff I added clarification.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have to write some extra code. For example:

```
if 'MICHAEL89' in map(lambda name: name.upper(), USERNAMES):
   ...
```

In this case we are forming a new list with all entries in `USERNAMES` converted to upper case and then comparing against this new list.

**Update**

As [@viraptor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31667/viraptor) says, it is even better to use a generator instead of `map`. See [@Nathon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391531/nathon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627784/case-insensitive-in-python/3627815#3627815).

Comment: Or you could use `itertools` function `imap`.  It's much faster than a generator but accomplishes the same goal.

Answer (score 5):

You could do

```
matcher = re.compile('MICHAEL89', re.IGNORECASE)
filter(matcher.match, USERNAMES)
```

Update:  played around a bit and am thinking you could get a better short-circuit type approach using

```
matcher = re.compile('MICHAEL89', re.IGNORECASE)
if any( ifilter( matcher.match, USERNAMES ) ):
    #your code here
```

The `ifilter` function is from itertools, one of my favorite modules within Python.  It's faster than a generator but only creates the next item of the list when called upon.

Comment: Just to add, the pattern might need to be escaped, since it might contain characters like ".","?", which has specail meaning in regular expression patterns. use re.escape(raw_string) to do it

Answer (score 1):

To have it in one line, this is what I did:

```
if any(([True if 'MICHAEL89' in username.upper() else False for username in USERNAMES])):
    print('username exists in list')
```

I didn't test it time-wise though. I am not sure how fast/efficient it is.

Comment: if you want to improve this time-wise: make it a single generator expression in the `any`. You currently have a list comprehension in a generator comprehension in the any call. Also the ternary `True if ... else False` that would also result `True` for a username like `abc_michael89xyz`!

Comment: I'd suggest `if any(name == username.upper() for username in USERNAMES):`

Comment: you are right about `abc_michael89xyz`, but I thought this is exactly the case that it should return `True` and exact match is not important

Comment: `a == b` can only yield `True` or `False` :) 

Comment: Ah now I know what you mean! But that's not what OP wanted! However this could just be `if any(name in username.upper() for username in USERNAMES):` Voilà!

Comment: The cool thing about this solution compared to most of the others is: That if done correctly `any` will already **end the loop** as soon as a first `True` is found! So this is not only performance but also memory friendly as there is no additional list created ad hoc

Answer (score 1):

Example from [this tutorial](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/python/python-string-contains-case-insensitive-example-code):

```
list1 = ["Apple", "Lenovo", "HP", "Samsung", "ASUS"]

s = "lenovo"
s_lower = s.lower()

res = s_lower in (string.lower() for string in list1)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

My 5 (wrong) cents

> 'a' in "".join(['A']).lower()

### UPDATE

Ouch, totally agree @jpp, I'll keep as an example of bad practice :(

Comment: This is wrong. Consider `'a' in "".join(['AB']).lower()` returns `True` when this isn't what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this for a dictionary instead of list, Jochen solution was the most elegant for that case so I modded it a bit:

```python
class CaseInsensitiveDict(dict):
    ''' requests special dicts are case insensitive when using the in operator,
     this implements a similar behaviour'''
    def __contains__(self, name): # implements `in`
        return name.casefold() in (n.casefold() for n in self.keys())
```

now you can convert a dictionary like so `USERNAMESDICT = CaseInsensitiveDict(USERNAMESDICT)` and use `if 'MICHAEL89' in USERNAMESDICT:`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Pyhton 3.10.5

Suppose I have a list

```
USERNAMES = ['joy23', 'michael89', 'rony224', 'samrat445']
```

Now if I want to check if 'michael89' is on the list without considering the case, The following code works:

```
'michael89'.casefold() in USERNAMES
```

The output will be true.

Again if I want to check if 'MICHAEL89' is on the list without considering the case, The code is:

```
'MICHAEL89'.casefold() in USERNAMES
```

The output will also be true.

```
'miCHAel89'.casefold() in USERNAMES
```

This returns true again.
[image: Example of the previous explanation]

**So the main catch here is the USERNAMES list should only contain lowercase letters. If you save all the items of USERNAMES in lowercase letters. You can simply solve the problem using**:

```
if 'MICHAEL89'.casefold() in USERNAMES:
    ......
```