# Finding a substring within a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

#### Background:

Example list: `mylist = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789']`

I want to retrieve an element if there's a match for a substring, like `abc`

#### Code:

```
sub = 'abc'
print any(sub in mystring for mystring in mylist)
```

above prints `True` if any of the elements in the list contain the pattern.

I would like to print the element which matches the substring. So if I'm checking `'abc'` I only want to print `'abc123'` from list.

Comment: You probably don't want to name a variable `list`, since that's the name of a built in data type (and you won't be able to do `list(x)` in the future)

Comment: Try filter. Should do what you need. Example here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640359/regular-expressions-search-in-list

Comment: @DavidRobinson it's just for the example

Comment: "it will print True for every element in the list." You are confused; it will print `True` only once, because `any` returns a single boolean value. It means exactly what it says: it returns a boolean that indicates if `any` of the listed things are true.

Comment: I'm not confused. That was the output, so I must've made a mistake in using `any` because it printed `True` for every element in the list.

Comment: there are too many incorrect statements in the question description. as @KarlKnechtel noted, any(...) statement would only print `True` once! the first code snippet is syntactically incorrect because `print string` is referring a variable that is out of scope. use of keywords `string` and `list` are anti-convention. I gave up on editing it! the later part needs to be completely re-written!

Answer (score 194, accepted):

```
print [s for s in list if sub in s]
```

If you want them separated by newlines:

```
print "\n".join(s for s in list if sub in s)
```

Full example, with case insensitivity:

```
mylist = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789', 'ABC987', 'aBc654']
sub = 'abc'

print "\n".join(s for s in mylist if sub.lower() in s.lower())
```

Comment: I think you should encourage use of generators when possible, such as in your second example :)

Comment: for case insensitivity use `sub.lower() in s` (thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627784/case-insensitive-in-python)

Comment: @mattwilkie Note that to be case insensitive you'd need `sub.lower() in s.lower()`, or it won't work when `s` is not lowercase.

Comment: oh. yes, thanks for catching that! The function I've been working passed my prototype data but would have failed on the real thing next week. (added example, remove if you don't like it)

Comment: mind to explain what is the reasoning behind `s for s in list if sub in s`  ? what does it even mean

Comment: I need it the other way around: several subs/needles and one string/haystack.

Comment: @Toskan it prints s zero, one or several times if sub is in s. This is list comprehension with filter: `[ EXP for x in seq if COND ]`

Comment: thats really weird python syntax, EXP and COND are so far apart... but thanks a lot for the explanation

Comment: Need to point out that using `list` as a variable name is bad practice since it overwrites the builtin `list` function.

Answer (score 85):

All the answers work but they always traverse the whole list. If I understand your question, you only need the first match. So you don't have to consider the rest of the list if you found your first match:

```
mylist = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789']
sub = 'abc'
next((s for s in mylist if sub in s), None) # returns 'abc123'
```

If the match is at the end of the list or for very small lists, it doesn't make a difference, but consider this example:

```
import timeit

mylist = ['abc123'] + ['xyz123']*1000
sub = 'abc'

timeit.timeit('[s for s in mylist if sub in s]', setup='from __main__ import mylist, sub', number=100000)
# for me 7.949463844299316 with Python 2.7, 8.568840944994008 with Python 3.4
timeit.timeit('next((s for s in mylist if sub in s), None)', setup='from __main__ import mylist, sub', number=100000) 
# for me 0.12696599960327148 with Python 2.7, 0.09955992100003641 with Python 3.4
```

Comment: Really great solution, by the way. I used it in some recent code.

Comment: That's a good point, thumbs up for you!

Comment: this is an interesting solution but if you put  ['abc123']  at the end of your "mylist" your solution will still take a very long time.

Comment: @Angelo Agree. The only reason this goes so fast is because it finds the match in the first element. So the time taken for this example is the BEST case. WORST case is it takes just as long (if it's not in the list). Still a good solution.

Answer (score 28):

Use a simple `for` loop:

```
seq = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789']
sub = 'abc'

for text in seq:
    if sub in text:
        print(text)
```

yields

```
abc123
```

Answer (score 14):

This prints all elements that contain sub:

```
for s in filter (lambda x: sub in x, list): print (s)
```

Answer (score 13):

I'd just use a simple regex, you can do something like this

```
import re
old_list = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789']
new_list = [x for x in old_list if re.search('abc', x)]
for item in new_list:
    print item
```

Comment: Why add complexity? The `in` operator is perfect for the job as seen in other responses. Regexes are a great tool, but I think it's a bit overkill here.

Comment: Very nifty piece of code.