# Iterate through a list and return the element that contains a specific word

Tags: python, list, search, contain

i have this code below:

```
wordSearch = "ghi"
lst = ['c:/test/abc.bat','c:/test/test1/def.bat','c:/123/ghi.exe','c:/test/testing/aa/jkl.bat']
```

by searching "ghi" I would like it to return "c:/123/ghi.exe". So, ultimately i want it to iterate through the list and return an element that contains specific text.

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: finding substring within a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779526/python-finding-substring-within-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
[item for item in lst if wordSearch in item]
```

The above line will return any item that contains `wordSearch`.

**Output:**

```
>>> wordSearch = "ghi"
>>> lst = ['c:/test/abc.bat','c:/test/test1/def.bat','c:/123/ghi.exe','c:/test/testing/aa/jkl.bat']
>>> 
>>> [item for item in lst if wordSearch in item]
['c:/123/ghi.exe']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that only return the first occurrence:

```
wordSearch = "ghi"
lst = ['c:/test/abc.bat','c:/test/test1/def.bat','c:/123/ghi.exe','c:/test/testing/aa/jkl.bat']

def find_word(wordSearch, lst):
    for path in lst:
        if wordSearch in path:
            return path

print(find_word(wordSearch, lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`:

```
 print filter(lambda x: 'ghi' in x, lst)
```

For Python3, above line will return a `filter` object. So, you need to use the factory function `list()` over it.

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: 'ghi' in x, lst)))
```