# Get Matched item from str(list)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I tried searching around , perhaps I am not getting exact way to search the web or stack overflow for this requirement. Kindly re-direct me or provide a solution for one's below.

I have a list say (My original list has over 10k cities)  :

```
A = ['BANGALORE', 'DUBAI', 'SHANGHAI' , 'SOUTH ASIA' , 'NORTH ASIA']
```

Now my requirement is match this list similar to `LIKE` operator in ORACLE. I mean , if we enter BAN  , it has to match BANGALORE. I accomplish this by following :

```
if 'BAN'in  str(A) :
   Do my stuffs
```

Now , if  I need to retrieve that element from list where 'BAN' matched . How can we do it ?

In simple terms .

```
if 'BAN'in  str(A) :
   Display to me what is that A that matched 'BAN'.
```

I did some searching around but couldn't find a a solution

Comment: well , i will need that value of A where BAN matched ! I have over 10k cities in the list.  I know i am matching BAN , but i do not know on what A is that matching. I want to find that !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: finding substring within a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779526/python-finding-substring-within-a-list)

Comment: Agree , That's what i have put in my post. I tried my ways to search but could not find one probably because of the wordings i used during search !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[city for city in A if 'BAN' in city]
```

This gives you a list with every city that contains 'BAN'. You can check if the list is empty and then print it or take the first element, or whatever you want to do.

```
matching = [city for city in A if 'BAN' in city]
if matching:
  print 'There are ', len(matching), ' cities that contain BAN.'
  print 'For example: ', matching[0]
```

Comment: I shall try out this solution before accepting this answer. Thank you very much :)