# Searching for specific lines in .db which contain keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that I'd like to find a certain keyword in using Python and display lines of database only containing them in a certain row:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect("corpus.db")
c = con.cursor()
keyword = str(input("Which keyword do you wish to find in the corpus? "))
c.execute("SELECT Content FROM Corpus")
#I'm guessing there should be more parameters here
```

I'm fairly new to coding in general, so sorry if the whole thing seems very noobish. I can't seem to find any similar solutions. I tried doing this (even though it's not exactly what I'm looking for, but I thought I could at least work around with the results from here later):

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect("corpus.db")
c = con.cursor()
keyword = str(input("Which keyword do you wish to find in the corpus? "))
#For example, "camera"
c.execute("SELECT Content FROM Corpus")
#In my case, content contains a list with this data [('A Japanese woman has been reunited with a camera she dropped in the ocean two-and-a-half years ago, after schoolchildren in Taiwan found it washed up on a beach and covered in barnacles.',), ('The writer is a Washington DC-based foreign affairs analyst. His views are his own.',), ...]
content = c.fetchall()
for text in content:
    if keyword in text:
        print(text)
```

So, theoretically, it should print the sentence about a Japanese woman, but it prints nothing, so I have no idea what I should do to actually find elements inside of a list even. It works in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779526/finding-a-substring-within-a-list-in-python) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my case, content contains a list with this data
>   [('A Japanese woman has been reunited with a camera she dropped in the ocean
>   two-and-a-half years ago, after schoolchildren in Taiwan found it
>   washed up on a beach and covered in barnacles.',), ('The writer is a
>   Washington DC-based foreign affairs analyst. His views are his
>   own.',), ...]

The returned values in `content` seems to be a list of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).
You'll have to iterate again within each tuple to get the sentence.

Like this:

```
for item in content:
    # item = ('A Japanese woman has been reunited with a camera she dropped in the ocean two-and-a-half years ago, after schoolchildren in Taiwan found it washed up on a beach and covered in barnacles.',)
    for sentence in item:
        if keyword in sentence:
            print(sentence)
```

Comment: Oh my god, thanks a lot! I couldn't figure it out at all.