# Not in list still gives me duplicate elements

Tags: python, list

this is the code that I have. As you can see I append every element to the list if the element is not already in the list but I noticed I still somehow get duplicate elements.

```
def getExtraData(table):
    extraData = list()
    for ele in table:
        extras = re.findall('\[(.+?)\]', str(ele[0]))
        for extra in extras:
            single = extra.split(", ")
            for s in single:
                if s not in extraData:
                    extraData.append(s)
    return extraData
```

Took a screenshot in pycharm debugger console to show that the element is really the same.

[image]

Why could this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

> Why could this happen and how can I fix it?

There is nothing to fix, everything is fine. You get "Box **S**et" and "Box **s**et" because these are **different strings**. If you want to be case-insensitive, store lowercase versions, and test on lowercase too, like

```
if s.lower() not in extraData:
  extraData.append(s.lower())
```

Furthermore, why do you use list at all? This should be just a set (which reduces computational complexity of `in` from `O(N)` to nearly `O(1)`)

```
def getExtraData(table):
    extraData = set()
    for ele in table:
        extras = re.findall('\[(.+?)\]', str(ele[0]))
        for extra in extras:
            single = extra.split(", ")
            for s in single:
                extraData.add(s.lower())
    return list(extraData)
```

or even a bit shorter (and slightly faster as we omit python looping)

```
def getExtraData(table):
    extraData = set()
    for ele in table:
        extras = re.findall('\[(.+?)\]', str(ele[0]))
        for extra in extras:
            extraData.update(map(str.lower, extra.split(", ")))
    return list(extraData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to lejlot, if you want to preserve the case of string when storing them in `extraData`, you could use a generator for the check part:

```
if s.lower() not in map(str.lower, extraData):
  extraData.append(s)
```

Inspired by [Case insensitive 'in' - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627815/1916449).

Since `extraData` is a `list` in your case, there shouldn't be any significant performance penalty to this solution.

Comment: this will be twice as slow (two iterations over list, and reallocation of the memory, as for each element in the generator you create a lower-case string, which, as immutable object, has to be copied), but of course the sime big-O complexity. Plus now you will get the first capitalization from the container stored, and so the process is ordering-dependent.