# Replace dataframe columns values with string if value contains case insensitive string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```py
id      familyHistoryDiabetes
0       YES - Father Diabetic
1       NO FAMILY HISTORY OF DIABETES
2       Yes-Mother & Father have Type 2 Diabetes
3       NO FAMILY HISTORY OF DIABETES
```

I would like to replace the column values with a simple 'yes' if the string contains 'yes' and 'no' if the string contains 'no'.

To do this I ran the following code:

```py
df['familyHistoryDiabetes'] = df['familyHistoryDiabetes'].apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if 'Yes' in x else 'No')
```

After running this I realised that this would miss cases where 'yes' was all uppercase:

```py
id      familyHistoryDiabetes
0       No
1       No
2       Yes
3       No
```

So I want to run similar code but to ignore case of 'yes' when searching for it.

To do this I tried a solution like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51782340/7373787) using casefold() like so:

```py
df['familyHistoryDiabetes'] = df['familyHistoryDiabetes'].apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if 'YES'.casefold() in map(str.casefold, x) else 'No')
```

But this did not work as it resulted in my dataframe becoming:

```py
id      familyHistoryDiabetes
0       No
1       No
2       No
3       No
```

I can imagine this is an easy fix but I am out of ideas!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `np.where` with `contains` with `case = False`

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['familyHistoryDiabetes'].str.contains('Yes',case = False),
                     'Yes', 
                     'No')
```

Answer (score 1):

With `str.extract`:

```
df["familyHistoryDiabetes" ] = df["familyHistoryDiabetes"].str.lower().str.extract("(yes|no)")

>>> df
   id familyHistoryDiabetes
0   0                   yes
1   1                    no
2   2                   yes
3   3                    no
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract` with `IGNORECASE` flag:

```
# regex.IGNORECASE = 2
df['new'] = df.familyHistoryDiabetes.str.extract('(Yes)', 2).fillna('No')
```

Output:

```
   id                     familyHistoryDiabetes  new
0   0                     YES - Father Diabetic  YES
1   1             NO FAMILY HISTORY OF DIABETES   No
2   2  Yes-Mother & Father have Type 2 Diabetes  Yes
3   3             NO FAMILY HISTORY OF DIABETES   No
```