# Search string in list not working as expected

Tags: python

I'm creating a project in Python where I have a list of strings as follows:

```
lst_characters = ['Abel', 'Abigail', 'Adon', 'Akira', 'Akuma', 'Alex', 'Balrog', 'Birdie', 'Blanka', 'C. Viper']
```

Then, I'm checking if a given string "let's say: `Akuma (foe)`" is in `lst_characters`.

The way I'm doing it is:

```
# Sample string to check if exists in the list: 
character = "Akuma (foe)"

# Lower all strings in the list: 
lst_characters = [x.lower().strip() for x in lst_characters]

# Lower the sample string and check if exists in the list: 
if (character.lower() in lst_characters): 
    print("Character (" + character + ") is in the list")
else: 
    print("Character (" + character + ") not found in the list")
```

And the result is:

> Character (Akuma (foe)) not found in the list

You can run this code [here - mycompiler.io](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/8JYcpqI).

I tried [this code - "using `any`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627815/12511801) and [this code - using `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843172/12511801) and none of the code shown in the answers shows me the desired result, that is:

> Show that there is an element called (`Akuma`) in the `lst_characters` that matches with the sample input `Akuma (foe)`.

Comment: `Akuma (foe)` is not in the list of characters. `Akuma` is though

Comment: You need to check it the other way because of the reason mentioned by @jakub: `[x for x in lst_characters if x in "Akuma (foe)"]`

Comment: It appears you do not know how the `in` operator works. I suggest learning about it. The way it works is that it loops through the whole list, and compares each list item to your input, to see if they are equal. `character in lst` is equivalent to `any([character == lst_item for lst_item in lst])`. Since there is no item in `lst_characters` that is literally equal to `'akuma (foe)'`, the `in` operator naturally doesn't return `True`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `character` not a tuple like `("Akuma", "foe")`? You seem to be conflating data structures with how you would *display* a particular data structure.

Comment: change if (character.lower() in lst_characters):  to if ((character.split())[0].lower() in lst_characters):
Might not be the best way in future but this works for your code

Comment: @RandomDavis thank you, Your explanation about the `in` operator is very clear - I'm self-learning Python :)

Comment: @chepner I'm self-learning Python and this is a little project I'm working on. I need to check more examples and the documentation for another data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking if the string `Akuma (foe)` exists in your list. It doesn't. `Akuma` however does.

You could turn your check around like this:

```
exists = any(x in character.lower() for x in lst_characters)
if exists: 
    print("Character (" + character + ") is in the list")
else: 
    print("Character (" + character + ") not found in the list")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (character.lower() in lst_characters):
```

to

```
if ((character.split())[0].lower() in lst_characters):
```

Comment: Interesting. The `character.split()` is equivalent to separate the string by spaces. Thank you. +1

Comment: this wouldn't work if the character was `"C. Viper"`, which is in the list of characters.

Comment: @jakub if he wanted to keep it super simple he could just use a blank space character to join them into one string, or change to C.Viper.  This solution wasn't perfect I know but I think it is still useful for him to see