# make the case insensitive for the input search text in file

Tags: python, string

How to make the case insensitive the result of a search entered with an input on a text.
For example if I enter "Poésie" he will find
But if I enter "poésie" he will not find.

I do not know how to use the Regex Re.ignorecase method for the INPUT variable

here is a simple example

```
import os
rep_cour = os.getcwd()

file = open(rep_cour+"/data/testmultiple/text1.txt","r")


search_word = input("enter a word you want to search in file: ")
if(search_word in file.read()):
    print("word found")
else:
    print("word not found")
```

thank you

**edit :**
With the casefold() method  it works

I found the solution as suggested by StarckOverflow here :

[str.casefold is recommended for case-insensitive string matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627784/case-insensitive-in)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert both `search_word` and `file.read()` to lower or upper. And then compare it as,

```
search_word.lower() in file.read().lower()
```

Comment: thank you. Your solution works if I write everything in a lowercase character. But I would like the result of the search to be insensitive to the case