# Python: Extract keywords from string

Tags: python, string, dataframe, substring

Hey Guys I am searching for a fast/efficient way to extract keywords (defined in a list) from a String (in a Dataframe) without being case sensitive or dependent on " " chars:

keys = ['I', 'love', 'Cookies']

String from df= "xxxxxxxxIxx xx cookies"

result should by either ['I'] or ['I', 'Cookies']

I am currently using f"({'|'.join(keys)}) which is case sensitive. What would you recommend for long strings in even longer dataframes :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"xxxxxxxxIxx xx cookies"` What do the x's represent here?

Comment: more or less random chars

Comment: So if they enter "calamity", you want to (somehow) know that the "i" is significant, and not all the other letters?  I'm not sure that's possible...

Comment: Okay my bad: Lets say that the keywords are well chosen and way longer than 1 char! The result should either be the first detected key from the list or all detected keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code as per your inputs:

```
my_str ="xxxxxxxixxx xx cookhes"
my_list = ["I", "love", "Cookies"]
if any(substring.casefold() in my_str.casefold() for substring in my_list):
    print('Contains element')
else:
    print('Not contain any element.')
```

More info on the following answer from StackOverflow:
[Case insensitive 'in'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627784/case-insensitive-in)